# 'Event' object has no attribute 'get' in pygame

Tags: pygame, event-handling, attributeerror

So I'm working with

> pygame==1.9.6 Python 3.8.2

```
from pygame import *
init()
running == True
while running:
    for event in event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
```

even only this code gives me error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 77, in
> <module>
>     for event in event.get(): AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'get'
> ```

other things like screen.blit(args), image.load(args), screen.fill(args), etc works perfect

Comment: Issue is cleared. 
So it was a name collision and import pygame instead of from pygame import * solves this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are having a namespace collision because of the way you have imported pygame:

```
from pygame import *
```

You are importing all the methods and attribute names in the pygame module directly into the same namespace as your program. That is not generally good practice and can result in the collision you are having, where the **event** variable you are trying to define locally is colliding with the existing **event** variable from the pygame module. Instead you should import it like this:

```
import pygame
```

Then access the items from the pygame module by prepending the module name to them. Like this:

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
```

If you do it this way you avoid the two **event**s being confused with each other.

Comment: Yeah it indeed was a name collision issue.

Answer (score 2):

pygame.event is getting replaced by whatever `event.get()` is returning in your for loop since you assign it to `event`. You need to use a different name. You could also use `import pygame` instead of `from pygame import *` to avoid this issue.